# Logitech K760 failing to pair. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: bluetooth, logitech

Just finished installing 13.04 on a 5,1 macbook pro. Everything was recognized and am VERY pleased with the OS. I would like to pair my bluetooth keyboard but I am getting fail messages. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks. Feel free to ask any clarifying questions. I used to use linux in 2006, but haven't used it since, so I am new to Ubuntu in its current iteration.

Edit: After attempting to connect via the included GUI it gives me a passcode to type in on my wireless keyboard, which I proceed to do. It hangs for about 10-12 seconds, then says 'Logitech K760 failed to connect' Thanks for the response.

Edit 2: Can confirm that the solution in this thread worked for me (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2101785) I am now typing this with my wireless keyboard! :)

Edit 3: While Edit 2's solution did work, I'd like to note that it only works if you keep your computer running at all times. Any restarts or shut downs and you have to run the process all over again. I find this very cumbersome. If anyone knows of any permanent solutions, I am all ears (or eyes in this case).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please specify "I am getting fail messages". What are you seeing and at what step does it fail exactly? Be specific. Keep in mind that we can't see your screen. Provide this information by **editing** your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GUI to launch the configuration process, as normal. The passkey printed on bluetooth gui is wrong, so you have to install some tools.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-hcidump
sudo apt-get install bluez-utils blueman
```

On a console type

```
sudo hcidump -at | grep -A 1 "User Passkey Notification"
```

which will display the correct passkey.

```
2013-09-25 14:35:40.653393
HCI Event: User Passkey Notification (0x3b) plen 10
bdaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX passkey 66235
```

Type the passkey on the bluetooth keyboard and hit enter.

Reboot and you could see that bluetooth gui still registers your new keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I followed Bralam's answer. But in 13.10 you do not need to install anything except hcidump.

So on a console type,

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-hcidump
```

and then

```
sudo hcidump -at | grep -A 1 "User Passkey"
```

Use the bluetooth gui to add the keyboard but ignore the numbers that the gui prompts. Instead type the passkey showing on the console. That will pair the keyboard. I am using a HP 4000 keyboard and it also worked.

Comment: Wow, this worked, thanks! Why doesn't the GUI get the correct passkey?

Comment: FYI, this also works for Logitech K480 keyboard.

Comment: For some reason, my Gembird keyboard connected via GUI only once. After that, the only working method is the one proposed here.